# Proving that limit (without using calculus) $(n^2 + n) ^{1/2} - n = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove, Without using Calculus. 
$$\lim_{n->\infty} \left((n^2 + n)^{1/2} - n\right) = \frac{1}{2} $$

I am taking an introduction to real analysis course going through Rudin.

My work so far, 
By definition, limit of a sequence $p$ has the following property: 
For every $\varepsilon > 0$ There is an integer $N$ s.t. $n \geq N$ implies that $d(p_n, p) < \varepsilon $.

Let $ \varepsilon  > 0$. Then we need to find an expression for $N$. So: 
$$ \left|\left((N^2 + N)^{1/2} - N\right) - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \varepsilon $$

I am wondering whether this is the right approach?

Comment: try to use the formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: Finding an $N$ with such property does not ensure you have the property for $n>N$, unless you have proved some kind of monotonicity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep it's essentially the right approach. We want to find $N$ so that if $n > N$, then

$$ \left|\left((n^2 + n)^{1/2} - n\right) - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \varepsilon $$

We know that
$\left((n^2+n)^{1/2} - (n + 1/2)\right)\left((n^2+n)^{1/2} + (n+1/2)\right) = (n^2+n)-(n+1/2)^2$ using a "difference of two squares". Hence given some $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\left|\left((n^2 + n)^{1/2} - n\right) - \frac{1}{2} \right| = \frac{\left|(n^2+n)-(n+1/2)^2 \right| }{\left|\left((n^2+n)^{1/2} + (n+1/2)\right)  \right|} = \frac{1/4}{(n^2+n)^{1/2}+n+1/2} < \frac{1}{4n}<\frac{1}{n}$$

We see that if $N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, then for any $n > N$,
$$\left|\left((n^2 + n)^{1/2} - n\right) - \frac{1}{2} \right| <\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} = \varepsilon$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I did not think of using different of two squares. Did you choose this approach because you wanted to get rid of the square root?

Comment: Yeah exactly, square roots are horrible. The reason you "know it's going to work" before trying is that if you do a difference of two squares, the $(a+b)$ term will still have square roots but it's going to be "large" so it will be easy to handle.